# Script not loading on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Recently I made my portfolio website and as I tested it today, everything works just fine on all of the most popular browsers. The problem is - I have access only to phones with Android and laptops with Windows. That way I am unable to test Apple devices and Safari itself.

For that, I asked my friend to visit my website on her phone (she has iPhone), so I can check if everything is ok. Unfortunately, when she entered my domain, Safari was unable to load JavaScript at all. What's even worse, she then installed Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, and the same stuff happened.

We were testing my website also on MacBook - that time also on Safari and Chrome. On Safari, there were some errors (it seems that at least part of the script worked), and on Chrome everything was right. I wasn't able to explore the problems, as we only had limited time via phone call.

Right now, my main issue is - **why any browser on iPhone was unable to load the script?** I would be very grateful if someone with iPhone or other Apple device could tell me what's happening there. The additional issue would be the Safari on MacBook. Because in this case, I was unable to detect anything useful, other than that only part of the script seems to be working.

Also, I don't know if that matters, but I used Webpack to bundle all JavaScript files. All code + domain can be found in the links below:

The website domain is: **[www.pmiecznik.pl](http://www.pmiecznik.pl)**

If you want to see those scripts/ style files - they are in the src folder in [**my GitHub repository.**](https://github.com/PRMK01/Portfolio)